# Forward `Application and Service Logs` as SNMP traps

Tags: windows, snmp, windows-event-log

Windows 2012 R2.
How to add EventLogs from `Application and Service Logs\Microsoft\Windows` to be able send them as SNMP traps using `evntcmd` utility.
I try find them using `evntwin` utility ant can not find them.
In particular I want add `RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS/Operational` events.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an easy way to send events from any log, including the RemoteDesktopServices operational log via SNMP, Syslog etc. without using multiple utilities & procedures then I would take a look at [EventSentry Light](http://www.eventsentry.com/downloads/select-edition).

It's a free real-time event log monitoring tool - setup and installation are very easy. The web site has lots of video tutorials as well.

Comment: Thanks. But I already solve my problem using nxlog. But my question is more why MS does not support this functionality for new EventLog API and is there any analog inside Windows itself. But I think it is rhetorical question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Interesting, I have never heard of nxlog. You can trigger processes from events in Windows, so as long as you have a command-line tool which can send SNMP traps it should be possible. I personally just don't think that it's worth the effort :-)